# Asp.Net multiple join tables issue from Sqldatasoruce Query Builder into one gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET 4, I am trying to join several tables together to put the results in a gridview and details view with sqldatasource. In the sqldatasource wizard I have chosen to specify a custom SQL statement or stored procedure and then in the Query Builder to define complex queries such as JOINs, I have tried to generate a SQL statement to join the problem table with speficific columns from other tables. But when I try to test the query I get an error message which says "Cannot call methods on varchar". I am new to sql statements so please can you advise on what is wrong with the statement.
Here is the generated sql statement below

```
 SELECT Problem.ProblemID, Problem.CustomerID, Problem.Summary, 
        Problem.DateLogged, Problem.DateUpdated, Status.Status, Priority.Priority, 
        Technician.Name, Technician.Surname, [Skill Group].[Skill Group], 
        HelpdeskOperator.Name AS Expr1,
        HelpdeskOperator.Surname AS Expr2, Problem.NoteID, Problem.ResolutionID 

 FROM Problem 
INNER JOIN Status ON Problem.StatusID = Status.Status.StatusID 

    INNER JOIN HelpdeskOperator ON 
    Problem.HelpdeskID = HelpdeskOperator.HelpdeskID AND Status.StatusID = HelpdeskOperator.StatusID 

    INNER JOIN Priority ON Problem.PriorityID = Priority.PriorityID 

    INNER JOIN [Skill Group] ON Problem.SkillGroupID = [Skill Group].SkillGroupID 

    INNER JOIN Technician ON Problem.ProblemID = Technician.ProblemID 
    AND Status.StatusID = Technician.StatusID AND
     Priority.PriorityID = Technician.PriorityID 
    AND [Skill Group].SkillGroupID = Technician.SkillGroupID
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your query:

```
SELECT p.ProblemID, p.CustomerID, p.Summary, p.DateLogged, p.DateUpdated, s.Status, pr.Priority, t.Name, t.Surname,
       sg.* , ho.Name AS Expr1, ho.Surname AS Expr2, p.NoteID, p.ResolutionID
FROM Problem p
INNER JOIN Status s ON p.StatusID = s.StatusID
INNER JOIN HelpdeskOperator ho ON p.HelpdeskID = ho.HelpdeskID AND s.StatusID = ho.StatusID
INNER JOIN Priority pr ON p.PriorityID = pr.PriorityID
INNER JOIN [Skill Group] sg ON p.SkillGroupID = sg.SkillGroupID
INNER JOIN Technician t ON p.ProblemID = t.ProblemID AND s.StatusID = t.StatusID AND pr.PriorityID = t.PriorityID
                         AND sg.SkillGroupID = t.SkillGroupID
```

1. You had duplicate table identifier in your join clause `Status.Status.StatusID`
2. I doubt that your `Skill Group` table contains column `[Skill Group]` so changed it to return all values from `Skill Group`

I just think those were the errors, if not I will need more info about your query and table structure.

**EDIT:**

First it did not return anything for `HelpdeskOperator`, look at our query:

```
INNER JOIN HelpdeskOperator ho ON p.HelpdeskID = ho.HelpdeskID AND s.StatusID = ho.StatusID
```

that meanse that here is no such `HelpdeskOperator` record that is assigned to our problem AND statusid, so either problem id points to noexisting helpdeskoperator or statusid of 
this operator is different that problem status id.

next is `Skill Group`

```
INNER JOIN [Skill Group] sg ON p.SkillGroupID = sg.SkillGroupID
```

again our problem point to no existing skill group

then `Technican`

```
INNER JOIN Technician t ON p.ProblemID = t.ProblemID AND s.StatusID = t.StatusID AND pr.PriorityID = t.PriorityID
                        AND sg.SkillGroupID = t.SkillGroupID
```

here is more work as more checks, technicas must be assigned to our problem with given status and priorityt and be in skill group, BUT our skill group is null? so to check if
there is technican for our problem remove `AND sg.SkillGroupID = t.SkillGroupID` so you get

```
INNER JOIN Technician t ON p.ProblemID = t.ProblemID AND s.StatusID = t.StatusID AND pr.PriorityID = t.PriorityID
```

and see if now we get any technican.

I hope this points you into right direction. You must be sure that there are matching record in every joining table.

Comment: Hi there, I tried your fix and now the error message is "The multi-part identifier "Technician.ProblemID could not be bound". Please could you help.

Comment: Please try again, was typo in my query :)

Comment: The tables I want to join are Problem table, Technician Table, HelpdeskOperator table, Skill Group table, Status table and Priority table each table has a ID as the foreign key in the problem table. The query is to return specific columns from the tables mentioned and join them as one result alongside values from the problem table. I wanted to test this first as ideally I wanted a dropdown list to filter the skill group table and all the results will be populated into the gridview.

Comment: I understand, but is there something wrong with my query? Is it working? Or is returning wrong results? I need more info :)

Comment: Hiya, the query has worked but for some reason when I run the webpage in visual studio it will not display the gridview, do you why?

Comment: First check if the query return any results at all (in SQL Server Management Studio) then because you are using `SqlDataSource` check if it is properly tied to `GridView` - my best bet is than in one of this place is error :)

Comment: Hi there, I am pretty sure that sqldatasource is tied to the gridview from the smart tag on the gridview, so I am not sure why it will not display anything?

Comment: Did you check if query returned at least one row?

Comment: On the design aspx page it shows the columns in the grdiview, but when I run the page the query did not return any row. No unfortunately the query does not return any row.

Comment: I see what you mean, the test query does not return any row.

Comment: Then there is no result that matches query meaning somewhere in table joining there is no matching result, fixing this requires access to db and query modification. First thing you can try is to change all `inner joins` into `left join` and see which columns are not returned (are `null`) and then check if joining parameters are right and if so, check in result table if id is present.

Comment: Hi there again, I used LEFT JOIN and the query returned rows for the Problem table EXCEPT THE COLUMN CUSTOMERID and from status and priority table. But it did not return rows from the skill group, technician and helpdesk operator table. Sorry, I did not quite understood the rest of your advise in how to return the null rows.

Comment: See my edit :). Hopefully you will find out what is going wrong in that query :)

Comment: Hi there, I have managed to sort most of the query out but I am missing two values from the helpdesk operator column i.e no records belonging to row 1 and 2  in helpdesk operator column, it retrieves the other helpdesk operators but not these two. I have also check continuously that there are matching records in every joining table. So must there still be something missing in my query? As its taken me so long to figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any errors in joining with helpdesk, any advice I can give is to remove joining by status and see if it works as: `INNER JOIN HelpdeskOperator ho ON p.HelpdeskID = ho.HelpdeskID`

Comment: Hi gzaxx, thank you so much, it now shows all the required rows and fields for now. Please I would like to ask 3 questions, if I want to use a dropdown list so that it lists the skills group and searches for all problems within that skills group in the gridview that list all columns from joining tables, is that possible as would I have to bound that dropdown list to the skills group table and how do I work with that? Secondly Could I join the customer table columns with 5  columns from the problem table by inner join? Thirdly how do I use the sqldatasource to submit a new problem into table?

Comment: This is because I do not want to use the details view to do this, I would like to use textboxes and dropdownlists to type in problems and select values from some of the dropdown list on the webform and use a button to submit the data in to the table.

Comment: 1. About join: you can join on how many columns you want, also in join clause you can add simple checking like `Problem.StatusId = 2` and it will work. About binding it is a bit wider topic but quite easily to get it going ([look here)[http://aquesthosting.headtreez.com/doc/99f4d65b-bb62-4ac1-b58a-008edc6a511d]). About SqlDataSource I do not have much experiance with it, but what are you asing for is easily done without it and I advice to not use it, just work with some ORM link LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework :)

Comment: Thank you so much gzaxx, with LINQ2SQL, silly question I know, but when you want to use a textbox the code will be, ".ProblemID = txtproblemid.Text" (Im using VB) but with a dropdownlist would the code be ".Status = ddlstatus.SelectedValue" As Im a little confused. Also I could not access the link you gave me

Comment: Sorry, this is the link (in c# but syntax for bidning is identical, just drop `;` :)) [link](http://aquesthosting.headtreez.com/doc/99f4d65b-bb62-4ac1-b58a-008edc6a511d) as for rest, yes you access selected value from ddl as ddl.SelectedValue (this is object so it could require casting) but only when ddl is databound! (for db table)

Comment: Thank you gzaxx, with databound, do you mean databound with the LINQ2SQL and what if I want most of the fields to be a dropdown list, can you have the option to do that?

Comment: Databound with List of objects (obtained from LINQ2SQL for example). You can have as many dropdown list as you wish, just bind them to their lists.

Comment: OK thank you, I think I need to post another question though as the dropdownlist that I want to bound to the gridview to display the different types of Skill Groups from the joined table you helped me with is not working, it just displays the skill group Hardware twice in the list. Please could you advise?

Comment: Please post new question and link me URL to it, answering through comments is painful! :)